# Java- How to get the HTML code from a URL including its AJAX generated code using Firebug or any Java library

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, parsing, firebug

I need to obtain the code from a web, which is in part "pure HTML" and in part HTML generated with AJAX, Javascript.

Since the easiest way to get it seems to be using Firebug, i've thought that it has to exist aome way to use Firebug or some plugin of it to be able to do it from Java code.

The problem i have is that after being searching through many webs and portals i have found nothing.

Anyone knows some way/ some plugin... which makes possible get this AJAX generated code mixed with the static HTML, as Firebug does?

Thanks and please excuse my english.

Comment: Look at http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Does this interpretation sound correct? You want to use Java to load the contents of a URL that contains any dynamically generated contents that would have been generated if the URL had been loaded using a web browser?

Comment: Not exactly; I need to obtain the code wich returns, i.e. Firebug, including the code generated using AJAX; If i watch the code in a simple browser, instead of i.e. a table generated with AJAX into the DIV "example", i just can see the DIV, not the dynamically generated code for it.

Firebug shows also this AJAX-generated-code.

Comment: Thats basically what I said. When you do a view-source, you see the source HTML of the page, firebug does not show you the source of the html, but the current structure of the DOM. AJAX and Javascript alter the DOM, but firebug can still show you the "effective' source code of the page in its current form.

Comment: Yes, you are right; i misread your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abhijeet is kinda on the right track, but I'm going to take the time to explain how browsers treat webpages and help you understand why your request is so difficult.

**Warning** This is quite rough and i am fudging some details for brevity and clarity

A browser connects to a server and uses HTTP to retrieve the page you have requested. When that page is downloaded, the browser then searches for any additional resources referenced in the page and retrieves them. It then executes any javascript it found top-to-bottom, including any referenced scripts. This javascript can manipulate the page, but by this point, the browser doesn't care much about the original source code of the page, having internalized it as a DOM, or Document Object Model. Javascript is actually just manipulating this DOM, since the DOM is just a tree structure, not doing any source-code manipulation. As a result, firebug (or the webkit inspector) don't actually display the source code, they display a representation of the current state of the DOM.

The problem with your request is that you want to use a separate system to load a url then go through the entire process above, unfortunately that would require you to implement an entire javascript engine, in Java.

However, all is not lost. HTMLUnit (mentioned by others), is a working, headless browser, written in Java, and as such you can integrate it into your program. Actually doing that is beyond the scope of this answer, but the homepage is [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and the API documentation is [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Yep. That's why i finally decided to ask about it here; because i didn't understood how something that would be so usefull like this wasn't implemented yet, at least not for using it as a library or plugin. But it seems its really not available.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do this is sniff what all GET/POST requests are being made. So, start the Firebug & see what GET/POST request is being made.

Then you can use [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) class to do that in Java code.

You can also try using a headless browser like [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).